# FitnessTest: _EXCEPTION__:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test (wrong name:

Tags: java, fitnesse-slim

I am new to fitnesse test
I have the following header in fitnesse test page

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path C:\install\fitness\


!|import|
|fitness|

!|Test|
|first|second|sum?|
|8|5|3|
```

class file found in the path mentioned above; each time I try to run the test I kept getting:

```
_EXCEPTION__:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test (wrong name: fitness/Test)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
```

Do you have any suggestion ?